# REST API and date field format

Tags: entities, 8

I have an angular front end with D8 backend. I am populating a content type that has a Date field. I am successfully creating the content-type with the all its fields including the Date field. The format I am sending via POST looks like `2017-07-07`. It gets saved and I can even retrieve the data.

The problem is when I edit or view the node via drupal admin, the date field is empty. If I devel the node, the value I sent is set on the field. It just will not display via in drupal. What format should I be sending the date field so it will save and populate the form.

In JS, I am sending the date like so:

```
var start = new Date();
var params = {
  start: {value: start.getFullYear() + '-' + (start.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + start.getDate()}
};
$http.post(API + 'entity/node', params); //etc
```

Comment: If you create the node (with a date field) via the Drupal UI, then do a `GET` on that node via REST, what does the structure of the date field look like?

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein good point...appears to look like: `2017-07-21T18:11:11`

Comment: What is the machine name of your date field? Perhaps something like `field_start`...?

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein yes it is field_start. It looks like it is expecting a time stamp as well as date. it looks like maybe a 24hr format?

Comment: What if you try POSTing something like this then in your params: `"field_start":[{"value":"2017-07-21T18:11:11"}]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a Date Field via REST in Drupal 8, you can do this:

```
// Build the JSON payload.
var node = {
  "type":[{"target_id":"article"}],
  "title":[{"value":"Hello World"}],
  "field_start":[{"value":"2017-07-21T18:11:11"}]
};

// Then POST the payload to Drupal...
$http.post('https://example.com/entity/node', node);
```